# How to add a foreign key in an existing table?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, alter-table

I have three tables:

**1. User** (id, name, birthdate)  - *PRIMARY KEY ('id')*

**2. Contact** ( id, contact, verified ) - *PRIMARY KEY ('id')*

**3. UserContact** ( User_id, Contact_id ) - *No Primary Key or Foriegn Key*

Problem is that I did not care of primary key or foreign key while creating **UserContact** table. Therefore I am getting following error while inserting record in **UserContact** table in zend framework.

> A table must have a primary key, but none was found

Now I want to create a MySql script that **alter UserContact** table and make **User_id** and **Contact_id** as foreign keys from User and Contact tables. How to write this script. I am using phpMyAdmin.

Thanks

Comment: if i'm not wrong you only need to declare it in zend framework with protected $_primary = 'id';//primary key
, declaring it in mysql only adds speed to the queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Add foreign keys -

```
ALTER TABLE UserContact
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserContact_User FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id);
ALTER TABLE UserContact
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserContact_Contact FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES user(id);
```

Add primary key -

```
ALTER TABLE UserContact
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (User_id, Contact_id);
```

Comment: Might be good to mention that only InnoDB supports them. And does MySQL create the indexes to support the FKs or do you have to do that by hand?

Comment: Yes, only InnoDb tables support foreign keys. After FK is created indexes will be created automatically.